# If padding bit is 51 and original message is 1263104 bits in MD-5 Hash function then how do I figure out the Length of the message?

Tags: hash, md5

I was going through some documents and I stumbled upon a problem, where it stated that "Based on MD5 hash function algorithm, if we need 2467 blocks or 1263104 bits and padding size is 51 bits. Then what would be the length of the message? "

I tried adding the bits like, 1263104 + 51 ( Padding bits ) + 461 ( additional Bits ) = 1263616. Is this the proper length of the message ? or Am I missing anything ?

Comment: Are you sure the padding is not supposed to be _subtracted_ from the total number of bytes?

Comment: @Botje, That is what I am confused about. Maybe I am not getting the question right. Help me out if you can. Thank you so much!